# Python error code AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, save

I made a Python steganography program. And then I want to save the outputted image with syntax object.save(). In the console log shows an error, that said

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'
```

I have tried many ways, but it's doesn't work. I have no idea to fix it and the codes below.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def int_to_bin(rgb):
    r, g, b = rgb
    return ('{0:08b}'.format(r), '{0:08b}'.format(g), '{0:08b}'.format(b)) 

def merge_rgb(rgb1, rgb2):
    r1, b1, g1 = rgb1
    r2, b2, g2 = rgb2

    rgb = (r1[:4] + r2[:4], g1[:4] + g2[:4], b1[:4] + b2[:4])

    return rgb

im = "bunga.jpg"
img1 =  Image.open(im,'r')

im2 = "index.jpg"
img2 = Image.open(im2,'r')

pixel_map1 = img1.load()
pixel_map2 = img2.load()

for i in range(img1.size[0]):
    for j in range(img1.size[1]):
        rgb1 = int_to_bin(pixel_map1[i, j])

        if i < img2.size[0] and j < img2.size[1]:
            rgb2 = int_to_bin(pixel_map2[i, j])
            rgb = merge_rgb(rgb1, rgb2)

merged_image = rgb
img = merged_image.save("decode_konversiGreykeBiner.jpg")
```

And this the error:

[image]

Comment: Your `merge_rgb` function creates and returns a tuple.  What class object were you expecting?  What class has a `save` method?  Tuple doesn't.

Comment: I expect after i merge the image i can save that the binary data to be an image file. I don't make any class.

Comment: `rgb` is just a tuple of the latest fused pixels. You don't put them in a new image, so every loop the previous one is discared. If you put your altered pixels in a new `Image` object, that does have a `save()` method which does what you want it to do.

Comment: With "save the binary date to be an image file", you probably meant to say save the pixels, which have embedded information in their least significant bits to an image. Because writing binary data to an image format means something different, although the result would techincally be the same.